# ListView shows wrong layout

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and in its adapter according to some situations I inflate layouts. for example consider this:

```
if (state1){
    resource = R.layout.layout_1

}else if (state2){
    resource = R.layout.layout_2
}
if (convertedView == null) {
    view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(resource, parent,false);
}               
return view;
```

But sometimes ListView gets confused and it shows same layout for different states. I am sure there nothing wrong in code. But in ListView behavior. Any Suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: How do you get the state? Is the state per row or per Listview?

Comment: I get the state according to the new added data :) But this is not the problem. Please look at my own answer :)

Comment: [Did you know `ListView` use recycling mechanism?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/1841194)

Comment: Yea but what I experienced was something other than recycling I think! Because it doesn't wait for old items to go out of the list(By Scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (state1){
view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_1, parent,false);

}else if (state2){
view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_2, parent,false);
}




return view;
```

Comment: Thanks but this is the same as what I wrote. I found the solution and will write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the Solution.

The problem is that I check if ConverView parameter is NOT null then the adapter doesn't inflate new view and it uses the last one. If I delete this condition and make the adapter to always inflate a new layout the problem gets solved.

Like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view;
int resource = 0;
if (state1){
    resource = R.layout.layout_1;
}else{
    resource = R.layout.layout_2;

}
//if (convertedView == null) { //I should Delete this condition
     view = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_2, parent,false);
//}
return view;
```